# How to access palette.secondary.light in material ui v5? TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to take the palette.secondary.light and apply it to the login button. My code has demo.tsx and theme.tsx files. Below is the link in codesandbox. Can someone help me?

[Code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/appbar-wyw72j?file=/demo.tsx:310-357)

Comment: I managed to apply using 

sx={{color: "secondary.contrastText",
  "backgroundColor: "secondary.light"
}}

Is there another way?

Comment: light and dark colors are used automatically in some components like in `progressbar` or `switches`. so if you want to intentionally use the light color then this is correct way. as light  color cannot be used with `color` prop

Comment: Your approach is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the useTheme hook is a good solution, Like this:

```js
import useTheme from '@mui/material/styles/useTheme'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'

const LoginButton = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()

  return <Button style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light }}>Login</Button>
}

export default LoginButton
```